# Delegate immutability and assignment operator

Tags: c#, delegates

I read that delegate are **immutable** objects.

If I have into a thread:

```
EventHandler handler = (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("...");
EventHandler copy = handler;
copy(new object(), EventArgs.Empty);
```

that copy is a thread safety operations so when I invoke `copy(...)`
if another thread eliminated the delegate from `handler` no exception can raise.

However If I make, i.e,:

`handler.GetHashCode()` and `copy.GetHashCode()` they both returns the same code.

I thought that the assignment operator did a new instance of that delegate
and that the new reference had put into `copy` variable...

How can, thus, `copy` and `handler` be independent if they both references
the same object in memory?

Confused!

Comment: You actual question seems to be _"does an equal hashcode mean both variables refer to the same instance"_, to which the answer is "no".

Comment: @CodeCaster However in this case both variables do reference the same object.

Comment: Immutable means you cannot change the object.  You can however assign a new object to `handler` (or even set it to null) and that change will not effect `copy`.

Comment: @CodeCaster, my question is on delegate immutability and assignment operator and not on exact meaning of GetHashCode.

Comment: @xdevel your wording: _"handler.GetHashCode() and copy.GetHashCode() they both returns the same code"_ and _"How can, thus, copy and handler be independent if they both references the same object in memory"_ makes it very clear that you think _"equal hash code means same object in memory"_, but whatever.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought that the assignment operator did a new instance of that delegate and that the new reference had put into copy variable...

No, it doesn't create a new instance. It assigns the current instance, so if *another thread* changes the registered delegates on the event, the current instance is remained the same. Since the event handler is immutable, the assignment on the event handler will result in a new object.

As a side note: strings are immutable too, but assigning one string to another doesn't copy it, aka 'makes a new instance'.

Comment: So after the copy, if a thread remove on `handler` the referencing delegate with `-=` operator, it is using, actually, the `Remove` method that creates a new `Delegate` that not contains the delegate passed as argument. So also if `copy` point to the same delegate the method is still there...

Comment: Yes, it is. @xdevel2000